# How do you add the Kivy directories so Sublime Text can compile using Kivy language?

Tags: python, text, sublimetext2, kivy

I've tried everything to get this to work and nothing worked. I tried installing all of the binary directories for Kivy but it didn't work. Is there a very simple way to allow Sublime Text to understand Kivy language.

I am using Windows 10 with Python 2.7.10.

Comment: You don't need to add paths to kivy, but presumably a syntax highlighting file for sublime text. I don't know what format it uses for this.

Answer (score 6):

For enabling highlighting of Kivy language in Sublime Text make following steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Write `IP` *(install package)*
3. Chose *"Install Package"*
4. Write `KV`
5. Found *KIVY install pack*.
6. Press it.
7. In right bottom part of window Sublime Text you will seen *"Plain Text"*. Press this and in this Syntax Bar choose *Kivy Syntax*.

Maybe it's not what you looking for, but when I looking solutions for my problem  I found this topic and here was solution without method explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions in the following site:

https://github.com/ivlevdenis/kivylng

> On Windows:
>
> cd %APPDATA%/Sublime Text 3/Packages/ git clone
>   https://github.com/ivlevdenis/kivylng.git "Kivy Language"

Comment: Link-only answers are not the way of SO. Links may be outdated someday. Put essential informations in your answer!